# Python turtle after drawing , click mouse inside drawing, clear screen and redraw

Tags: python-turtle

I am working on using python turtle to draw a circle.when i draw the circle, mouse click inside circle erase, click anywhere in the turtle,redraw it and click again inside again erase. So the process like this :

black screen

1.Click mouse
2.Start drawing circle
3.finish
4.click inside circle
5.clear screen
6.click again anywehre in the screen redraw circle
7.click inside circle clear screen

Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR8CH.png

import PositionService

import turtle

t=turtle.Turtle()

ts=tur

tle.Screen()

ts.bgpic("shape_window.png")

t.up()

def get_click(x,y):# get click (x,y)

```
    #if counter == 0:

    draw_circle(x,y,"green",80)# draw the circle

    print("clicking at ({}, {})".format(x,y))
```

def draw_circle(x,y,color,rad):       # draw the circle

```
t.goto(x,y)

t.down()

t.circle(80)

t.color("green")

t.up()

t.hideturtle()

#t.home()
```

def main():

```
#maybe use global _pen

ts.onclick(get_click)  # clicker

#set_position( x,y)? 

#is_visible(draw_square)
```

Comment: is there a code that you are using to make this happen? put that here. show us what you have got so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think were from the same class. I was also struggling until I realized that they supplied a PositionService.py file. You are supposed to use the functions within that file to help.